# char * vs char[]

Tags: c, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C Program String Literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774770/c-program-string-literals)
>   [Bus error: 10 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716714/bus-error-10-error)

Using Xcode 4.5.2 for C, I thought

```
char * string = "abc";
string[0] = 'f';
```

and

```
char string[4] = "abc";
string[0] = 'f';
```

were equivalent.  But the first line gives me an error:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x100 ...)

And the second line gives me NO error. I thought these were equivalent in straight C. What's going on?

```
int main (void) {
    char * string = "abc";   
    string[0] = 'f';
} // main
```

Comment: There was a question about this just the other day - but I can't find it. Can anyone help find it?

Comment: @PreetSangha There is a question about just this roughly every other day :)

Comment: If you are a newbie in c, you ask direct question to searchengine such as in my case. Receiving minus and marking as duplicate dont newbies to learn less like me. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 9):

They are not the same.

```
char* s = "bla"
```

The above has s point to the memory location where the string literal is stored. Since this is a read-only memory (the literal is constant) the write to it fails.

```
char s[4] = "bla";
```

This fills the buffer `s` (which was allocated on the stack) with the contents of the literal. You can write to this buffer since it isn't const memory.

The reason why the first syntax is considered legal and doesn't raise an error related to const correctness, has to do with maintaining backwards compatibility with older versions of c.

Comment: Thank you all for disabusing me of my misconception.

Answer (score 1):

These are not equivalent as you've discovered.  The first is undefined behavior, as string constants are constant (that is `const char * const`). They may be in read-only memory (bad access, address 0x100 is a nice clue), which you are trying to modify through the first `string` (which is a `char *`).  The second `string` is actually an array of `char` which has storage (in this case on the stack) which may be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The first pointer points to a protected memory where strings from the programs are loaded.

The second pointer points to a newly allocated field of 4 chars.

Hence writing to the first field reports illegal access to memory.