# How to store a string into a char pointer?

Tags: c

I have a confusion with the following program

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char *string;
string = (char *)malloc(5);
string = "abc";  // <<<<<<<<<< why *string="abc" is not working. How string = "abc" is working?
printf("%s", string);
}
```

But the same program with integer is working

```
char *i;
 i=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
*i=4;  <<<<<<<< this is working fine
printf("%d",*i);
```

Comment: always prefer `int main(void)` over `void main()`

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `*string = "abc"` is not working?

`string` is defined as pointer to char. `*string` is a char. `"abc"` is a string literal. You are actually assigning address of string literal to char and compiler should issue warning like:

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

For example, `*string = 'a';` will work because just one char is assigned.

How `string = "abc"` is working?

Because address of string literal `"abc"` is assigned to `string` which is a pointer to char.

And BTW, doing that you lost previously allocated memory by `malloc()` and produced memory leak.

How to store a string into a char pointer? You can use just:

```
strcpy(string, "abc");
```

Comment: So u mean to say that when ever we assign a string literal, it would be stored somewhere in the memory and that address would be assigned?

Comment: Yes. Additionaly using `char *string = "abc";` you cannot change content later. See for example [C Program String Literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774770/c-program-string-literals)

Answer (score 1):

`*string` is  point out the single character.Here `"abc"` is string literal. It is not a character.

```
*string='a'; // It will work.
```

[Don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the result of malloc and its family.

You can use the `strcpy` function to do this.

```
strcpy(string,"abc");
```